# Exchange 2010msExchExtensionAttribute not found in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I don't find the Attribute msExchExtensionAttribute1-45 in the ActiveDirectory schema.

How could this be possible, I've done the exchange adprep by installing the exchange server.
Or might I miss an (optional) adprep?

Answer (score 0):

msExchExtensionAttribute's16-45 comes with SP2.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/01/17/custom-aka-extension-attributes-in-exchange-2010-sp2-and-their-use.aspx